# How to use sed to extract substring

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, xml-parsing, sed

I have a file containing the following lines:

```
  <parameter name="PortMappingEnabled" access="readWrite" type="xsd:boolean"></parameter>
  <parameter name="PortMappingLeaseDuration" access="readWrite" activeNotify="canDeny" type="xsd:unsignedInt"></parameter>
  <parameter name="RemoteHost" access="readWrite"></parameter>
  <parameter name="ExternalPort" access="readWrite" type="xsd:unsignedInt"></parameter>
  <parameter name="ExternalPortEndRange" access="readWrite" type="xsd:unsignedInt"></parameter>
  <parameter name="InternalPort" access="readWrite" type="xsd:unsignedInt"></parameter>
  <parameter name="PortMappingProtocol" access="readWrite"></parameter>
  <parameter name="InternalClient" access="readWrite"></parameter>
  <parameter name="PortMappingDescription" access="readWrite"></parameter>
```

I want to execute command on this file to extract only the parameter names as displayed in the following output:

```
$sedcommand file.txt
PortMappingEnabled
PortMappingLeaseDuration
RemoteHost
ExternalPort
ExternalPortEndRange
InternalPort
PortMappingProtocol
InternalClient
PortMappingDescription
```

What could be this command?

Comment: Note that you're going to be sad when that XML comes to you on multiple lines, or if the order of the arguments changes.  If that's at all a possibility, you'll want to look into using a proper XML parser.

Comment: Hm, double standard with questions that can be answered in 10 seconds vs. ones that require more time? Where is the post asking what you've tried? Oh wait...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want `awk`.

This would be a quick and dirty hack:

`awk -F "\"" '{print $2}' /tmp/file.txt`

```
PortMappingEnabled
PortMappingLeaseDuration
RemoteHost
ExternalPort
ExternalPortEndRange
InternalPort
PortMappingProtocol
InternalClient
PortMappingDescription
```

Comment: `cut` will do the job faster :-)

Comment: `awk` is link the nuke, when you just need to blow.

Answer (score 138):

**grep** was born to extract things:

```
grep -Po 'name="\K[^"]*'
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  echo '<parameter name="PortMappingEnabled" access="readWrite" type="xsd:boolean"></parameter>
  <parameter name="PortMappingLeaseDuration" access="readWrite" activeNotify="canDeny" type="xsd:unsignedInt"></parameter>
  <parameter name="RemoteHost" access="readWrite"></parameter>
  <parameter name="ExternalPort" access="readWrite" type="xsd:unsignedInt"></parameter>
  <parameter name="ExternalPortEndRange" access="readWrite" type="xsd:unsignedInt"></parameter>
  <parameter name="InternalPort" access="readWrite" type="xsd:unsignedInt"></parameter>
  <parameter name="PortMappingProtocol" access="readWrite"></parameter>
  <parameter name="InternalClient" access="readWrite"></parameter>
  <parameter name="PortMappingDescription" access="readWrite"></parameter>
'|grep -Po 'name="\K[^"]*'
PortMappingEnabled
PortMappingLeaseDuration
RemoteHost
ExternalPort
ExternalPortEndRange
InternalPort
PortMappingProtocol
InternalClient
PortMappingDescription
```

Comment: Just FYI, from the grep manpage regarding `-P`: "This is highly experimental and **grep -P** may warn of unimplemented features."

Comment: Not all *nix distros support 'grep -o'. One instance I know of is AIX

Comment: @FukuzawaYukio I think the grep shipped by ubuntu linux should support it right? even though I am not ubuntu user. The question was tagged with Linux & ubuntu, not Unix or Aix. But you comment is correct.

Comment: @Kent Right, I forgot to check what the question was targeting. Ubuntu's grep does indeed support `-o`.

Comment: I had to look up `\K`: It keeps what's left of it outside of the match (so you don't get `name="PortMappingLeaseDuration"`. [Further reading](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)

Comment: For those not wanting to use the `-P` flag; no other extended regex that is supported by the default grep will do what the `\K` does, but you could simply pipe it through sed: `grep -o 'name="[^"]* | sed 's/name="//g'`

Comment: Alternatively you can also use grep twice: `grep -o 'name="[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'`. It produces the same result.

Comment: Yea, no `-P` on MacOS: `grep: invalid option -- P`

Comment: @sh37211 most linux distros preinstall the gnu impl. The question has tagged "Linux" Please check Leon's comment above if -P is not available in your grep impl.

Comment: In my case on mac `grep` regex didn't work without `-E` option, so the final command is `grep -Eo 'name="[^"]* | sed 's/name="//g'`

Comment: @durex the question is tagged with `linux`. On MacOS, if you didn't install related GNU utilities, such as gnu grep, gnu sed, gnu awk. The options could be different from them in Linux.

Answer (score 122):

`sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'`

does the job.

explanation of the part inside ' '

- s    - tells sed to substitute
- /    - start of regex string to search for
- [^"]* - any character that is not ", any number of times. (matching *parameter name=*)
- "    - just a *"*.
- ([^"]*) *-* anything inside () will be saved for reference to use later. The \ are there so the brackets are not considered as characters to search for. [^"]* means the same as above. (matching *RemoteHost* for example)
- .*   - any character, any number of times. (matching *" access="readWrite"> /parameter*)
- / - end of the search regex, and start of the substitute string.
- \1 - reference to that string we found in the brackets above.
- / end of the substitute string.

basically s/search for this/replace with this/ but we're telling him to replace the whole line with just a piece of it we found earlier.

Comment: That's neither simple nor elegant. Just cryptic.

Comment: @Stefan, to the untrained eye perhaps. But spend time with RegEx and like jazz or Picasso, you'll appreciate the simple beauty.

Comment: That's what cryptic means: completely unreadable to the untrained eye.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question instead of proposing a different tool!

Comment: ITT: a generation growing up without learning powerful fundamentals like regular expressions! *sigh* Granted, awk, grep, perl, sed, lex, yacc, javascript all use slightly different variations (thanks posix!) but still an extremely powerful programming concept. I'm aghast at the complexity of some of the answers.

Comment: While it does the job, it would be beneficial if you actually explain what is  going on.

Comment: I always forget we need escape ( )

Comment: Cryptic but insanely powerful. Worth the time learning regexes, believe me.

Comment: The comment saying this is neither simple nor elegant has not read the question.

Comment: @unxnut This is such a good explain it help me a lot thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks mate! You are the best! So many useful info in a single reply =)

Comment: perfect tool for the job. at least that how I feel about it given I never understood awk and rarely use grep in an extended way. Also, it's very flexible to be further customized

Comment: not sure but from my tests, if it doesn't find a suitable fit, it returns the whole input, no?

Answer (score 19):

You should not parse XML using tools like sed, or awk. It's error-prone.

If input changes, and  before name parameter you will get new-line character instead of space it will fail some day producing unexpected results.

If you are really sure, that your input will be always formated this way, you can use `cut`.
It's faster than `sed` and `awk`:

```
cut -d'"' -f2 < input.txt
```

It will be better to first parse it, and extract only parameter name attribute:

```
xpath -q -e //@name input.txt | cut -d'"' -f2
```

To learn more about xpath, see this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Answer (score 14):

Explaining how you can use `cut`:

`cat yourxmlfile | cut -d'"' -f2`

It will 'cut' all the lines in the file based on **"** **d**elimiter, and will take the **2**nd **f**ield , which is what you wanted.

Comment: You want to avoid the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) though.