# In Linux command line console, how to get the sub-string from a file?

Tags: linux

The content of the file is fixed.

Example:

```
2016-03-28T00:02 AAA 2016-03-28T00:03  ADASDASD
2016-03-28T00:03 BBB 2016-03-28T00:04  FAFAFDAS
2016-03-28T00:05 CCC 2016-03-28T00:06  SDAFAFAS
....
```

Which command can I use to get all sub-strings, `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`, etc.

Comment: use [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) command

Comment: @BillBEGUERADJ how would you use `grep`? He wants to get all the substrings, not search for a string of text.

Comment: Or [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sed to extract substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675179/how-to-use-sed-to-extract-substring)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `cut` and `awk` and `perl` for this.

```
cat >> file.data << EOF
2016-03-28T00:02 AAA 2016-03-28T00:03  ADASDASD
2016-03-28T00:03 BBB 2016-03-28T00:04  FAFAFDAS
2016-03-28T00:05 CCC 2016-03-28T00:06  SDAFAFAS
EOF
```

#### AWK

```
awk '{ print $2 }' file.data
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

#### CUT

```
cut -d " " -f2 file.data
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

#### PERL

```
perl -alne 'print $F[1] ' file.data 
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print-Examples.html) for this:

```
jayforsythe$ cat > file
2016-03-28T00:02 AAA 2016-03-28T00:03 ADASDASD
2016-03-28T00:03 BBB 2016-03-28T00:04 FAFAFDAS
2016-03-28T00:05 CCC 2016-03-28T00:06 SDAFAFAS
jayforsythe$ awk '{ print $2 }' file
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

To save the result to another file, simply add the redirection operator:

```
jayforsythe$ awk '{ print $2 }' file > file2
```

Comment: how to save the result to another file? Thanks,@stanpines

Comment: @RhysJ anytime! If you liked my answer, do you mind pressing the checkmark to mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
cut -d' ' -f 2 file
```

Comment: or, without the `cat`, `cut -d' ' -f2 file`